# Alter price of woocommerce PDF invoice

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I must change the price on the woocommerce PDF invoice without changing the prices displayed in the orders.
The reason is to be able to invoice a seller but without the price of his product on the invoice.

I tried to use the "pdf_template_line_output" hook but I don't see how the to debug, and the changes I made from this function don't have any impact on the pdf, so if someone can shed some light on it I'm very grateful.

```
add_filter ( 'pdf_template_line_output' , 'custom_pdf_lines', 10, 2 );
function custom_pdf_lines ( $line, $order_id ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $order   = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // * * * * *  How to debug here? * * * 
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($order);
    echo "</pre>";

    $pdflines = "<table>";
    $pdflines .= "<th>test</th>";
    $pdflines .= "</table>";
    return $pdflines;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: See this guide - [WooCommerce: Easily Get Order Info (total, items, etc) from $order Object](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/)

Comment: Thank you @sky but my question here is "how to alter price only from the pdf invoice" ? is there a filter?

Comment: Are you using  any plugin to download invoice as pdf?

Comment: To change the price must first take it. Or take price - ```$order->get_total();```then changed it?

Comment: @MominIqbal i use woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips

Comment: Please check documentation here: https://docs.wpovernight.com/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/displaying-product-attributes/


Please check this too which has the tips on how to custmoize the PDF template using hooks and fitlers: http://docs.wpovernight.com/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/creating-a-custom-pdf-template/#customizing-the-template

Hope this will help

Comment: @MominIqbal, thanks you're right, i have to copy the template to my child theme and able to modify now.